# Android NoSuchMethodError with APK file (Apache HTTPUtils core)

Tags: android, eclipse

I use the Apache HTTPUtils core library 4.1.4 in my project to use the

```
EntityUtils.consume(HTTPEntity);
```

method.

However, when this method is used in the app in the emulator (SDK v.2.1), it crashes with a NoSuchMethodError.

I guess this is because the app tries to use the Android library which is old and doesn't have this method instead of the newer one I've put in my build path.

How can I use force the app to use the newer library?

Comment: Check out [Using newer version of HttpClient on Android (like 4.1.x)](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-newer-version-of-httpclient-like-4-1-x/).

Comment: Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worth to check out [Using newer version of HttpClient on Android (like 4.1.x)](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-newer-version-of-httpclient-like-4-1-x/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are right with your guess and you are using Eclipse you can change the order in "Order and Export" tab in Java Build Path options. If you have duplicate classes than you can define the class path order there

Comment: oops, I upvoted yesterday, but this actually just makes the compiler happy, not Android.